# How do I compress a directory?

Tags: compression, gzip, zip

I'm trying to compress a directory and ftp it to a windows ftp.

I have tried every tar command I can find to compress a directory. It appears to be ok. Then I transfer it and view it's contents using Winrar. Winrar keeps telling me the file is corrupted. I have viewed other .gz or .bz2 files using winrar but for some odd reason I can't get it to work.

I would prefer just to have it zip the files so they have a .zip extension but even then when i try to browse it's contents both windows and winrar claim it's corrupt.

Does anyone else have a suggestion as to something else to try?

Comment: (1) what exact tar command are you using? (2) can you untar the resulting file?

Comment: Try using 7zip to view the file in Windows.

Answer (score 383, accepted):

Well, most probably your files are perfectly fine before FTP transmission.

Unfortunately, probably you are transferring your files using wrong FTP mode.

FTP do have two modes: binary and ASCII. By default most clients use ASCII mode, which breaks your binary files completely. I don't know which FTP client you are using, but for example in [ncftp](http://www.ncftp.com/) you can use command "binary" to switch to binary mode.

If you want to create ZIP files using Ubuntu (or almost any other Linux), use `zip`. You can install it to Ubuntu by running

```
sudo apt-get install zip
```

Then you can create zip file by running

```
zip -r compressed_filename.zip foldername
```

---

On related note, you should know that FTP is insecure transmission protocol. Consider switching to sftp, for example. There is many free ssh servers for Windows, including [minimal OpenSSH port](http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Good point typically i relied on the client/server to automatically detect ascii vs binary mode and haven't had a problem so I never thought of that as a potential problem. I've ran zip before also and everything appeared fine until I tried to view it. Probably due to the binary/ascii thing.

Comment: Anyhow wow thank you, I feel like an idiot now that it was that simple. I should have known that. Anyhow thanks for the tip about the ssh for windows, eventually i was going to switch to that but i know ftp for windows throws fewer variables into the testing and developing factor.

Answer (score 77):

Campression can be done using tar, zip, p7 and even rar in ubuntu. You will need to install rar for rar archiving.
Simply right clicking gives you the options for compressing with installed archivers. 
[image]

If you want to use "zip" for .zip extentension you can see manual of zip. The commandline for using tar is:

```
tar cvzf tarball.tar.gz directory/
```

Comment: Awesome theme! What's the name of it?

Comment: is there any "-q" for "quite mode"?

Comment: @MatheusJardimB take out the v option `tar czf tarball.tar.gz directory/`

Comment: `c` means create, `z` means compress, `v` is verbose and `f` is create a new file.

Answer (score 7):

Compression of directories, using parallel compression is an efficient way to save time.
pbzip2 can help you getting directories compressed.

```
tar cf <outputfile_name> --use-compress-prog=pbzip2 <directory_name>
```