# How to compress and download directory from remote to local?

Tags: compression, scp

I have a directory on my Ubuntu server that has many subdirectories and files. I want to download entire folder, so I used this command:

```
scp -r myuser@mywebsite.com:/path/to/target_directory /path/to/local_directory
```

So target_directory ends up in /path/to/local_directory/target_directory. This is fine so far.

**The problem:** target_directory is not so big (around 50MB) but has many tiny files. `scp` download files one by one, which takes too long. So I'm thinking may be there's a way to compress the directory and download it (optionally, without keeping the compressed file on the server). I think it's achievable but not sure how.

**Note:** I use Mac for my local machine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I compress a directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27349/how-do-i-compress-a-directory)

Comment: @mikewhatever i'm trying to compress and download directory on the fly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need compression, if the problem is that there are many small files. Use `tar` to make an archive on Ubuntu, and instead of saving the archive to a file, send it to stdout (the default for Ubuntu's GNU tar when there's no file specified) and read the `tar` file on the other end:

```
ssh ubuntu-server tar c -C /path/to/target_directory . | tar xvf - -C /path/to/local_directory
```

Or use a smarter tool like `rsync`.

Comment: This is what I've happen looking for! Would be great if you can provide `rsync` example like the one you wrote for ssh.

Comment: @evilReiko pretty much what you'd do with `scp`, just that the options are different: `rsync -aP myuser@mywebsite.com:/path/to/target_directory /path/to/local_directory` (`-a` ~ archive - preserve owner, mode, etc., `-P` show progress)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @muru for answer and explanation. I'm posting this to remind myself and anyone else who might need this.

`rsync` is really fast! This is how to do it with `rsync`:

```
rsync -azP myuser@mywebsite.com:/path/to/target_directory/ /path/to/local_directory
```

- `-a` will (recursively) copy everything
- `-z` will compress the files,
- `-P` will show you progress bar for each file

`rsync` allows you to resume downloading in case of interruption or network failure just by running same command.

**Note:** the `/` in the right end of the source `/path/to/target_directory/` means it will copy the **content** of target_directory (not the directory itself). If you want to copy the directory itself then remove this trailing slash.

Read more: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-rsync-to-sync-local-and-remote-directories-on-a-vps